# Status code of response is incorrect in after_request hook in a bottle app

Tags: python, bottle

I have the following Bottle application:

```
from bottle import Bottle, run, request, response, HTTPResponse

APP1 = Bottle()


@APP1.hook('before_request')
def before_request():
    print "APP 1 - Before Request {}".format(request.url)


@APP1.hook('after_request')
def after_request():
    print "APP 1 - After Request {}".format(request.url)
    print "Response status {}".format(response.status_code)


@APP1.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"


@APP1.route('/error')
def error():
    raise HTTPResponse(status=400)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(APP1, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

When I hit the following url: `http://127.0.0.1:8080/error` I expect a response code of 400 to be printed but instead it prints 200.

```
APP 1 - Before Request http://localhost:8080/error
APP 1 - After Request http://localhost:8080/error
Response status 200
```

I know I can use the Plugin concept to implement an around advice but this means we cannot use `after_request` event hook to process error status codes. Besides it seems counter intuitive.

Is my setup incorrect? Or is my understanding of `after_request` event hook for Bottle incorrect?

Please advice.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to use `after_request`?  (Why wouldn't a simple plugin suffice?)